# How Relocate Interrupt Vectors MSP430FR5969

Tags: bootloader, msp430

I can't find the correct way to relocate Interrputs Vectors with CCS6.2 for MSP430FR5969.

The blink led application use TIMER_A0 :

```
#include "msp430.h"

#define DOUBLE_BLINK


//#pragma LOCATION(main, 0xF000)
void main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT

  PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

  // Setup GPIO
  P1OUT &= ~0x01;                           // Set P1.0 to output low
  P1DIR |= 0x01;                            // P1.0 output

  // Setup Timer_A3
  TA0CCTL0 = CCIE;                          // TA0CCR0 interrupt enabled
  TA0CCR0 = 32768;                          // ~1s
  TA0CTL = TASSEL_1 + MC_2;                 // ACLK, contmode

  P1OUT |= 0x01;                            // P1.0 = On
  __delay_cycles(500000);                   // Wait 500ms
  P1OUT &= ~0x01;                           // P1.0 = Off


  __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);       // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupt
}


// Timer A0 interrupt service routine
#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer0_A(void)
{
    P1OUT |= 0x01;                            // P1.0 = On
    __delay_cycles(100000);                   // Wait 100ms

#ifdef DOUBLE_BLINK
    P1OUT &= ~0x01;                           // P1.0 = Off
    __delay_cycles(100000);                   // Wait 100ms
    P1OUT |= 0x01;                            // P1.0 = On
    __delay_cycles(100000);                   // Wait 100ms
#endif

    P1OUT &= ~0x01;                           // P1.0 = Off
    TA0CCR0 += 32768;                         // Add Offset to TA0CCR0 (~1s)
}
```

This code work fine with standard interrupt vectors locations: here's the linker :

```
/* ============================================================================ */
/* Copyright (c) 2016, Texas Instruments Incorporated                           */
/*  All rights reserved.                                                        */
/*                                                                              */
/*  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without          */
/*  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions          */
/*  are met:                                                                    */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright           */
/*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.            */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright        */
/*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the      */
/*     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.     */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of      */
/*     its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived      */
/*     from this software without specific prior written permission.            */
/*                                                                              */
/*  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" */
/*  AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,       */
/*  THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR      */
/*  PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR            */
/*  CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,       */
/*  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,         */
/*  PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; */
/*  OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,    */
/*  WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR     */
/*  OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,              */
/*  EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.                          */
/* ============================================================================ */

/******************************************************************************/
/* lnk_msp430fr5969.cmd - LINKER COMMAND FILE FOR LINKING MSP430FR5969 PROGRAMS     */
/*                                                                            */
/*   Usage:  lnk430 <obj files...>    -o <out file> -m <map file> lnk.cmd     */
/*           cl430  <src files...> -z -o <out file> -m <map file> lnk.cmd     */
/*                                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* These linker options are for command line linking only.  For IDE linking,  */
/* you should set your linker options in Project Properties                   */
/* -c                                               LINK USING C CONVENTIONS  */
/* -stack  0x0100                                   SOFTWARE STACK SIZE       */
/* -heap   0x0100                                   HEAP AREA SIZE            */
/*                                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Version: 1.188                                                             */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/****************************************************************************/
/* Specify the system memory map                                            */
/****************************************************************************/

MEMORY
{
    SFR                     : origin = 0x0000, length = 0x0010
    PERIPHERALS_8BIT        : origin = 0x0010, length = 0x00F0
    PERIPHERALS_16BIT       : origin = 0x0100, length = 0x0100
    RAM                     : origin = 0x1C00, length = 0x0800
    INFOA                   : origin = 0x1980, length = 0x0080
    INFOB                   : origin = 0x1900, length = 0x0080
    INFOC                   : origin = 0x1880, length = 0x0080
    INFOD                   : origin = 0x1800, length = 0x0080
//    FRAM                    : origin = 0x4400, length = 0xBB80
    FRAM                    : origin = 0x4400, length = 0xBB00 // realoc du realoc VI
    FRAM2                   : origin = 0x10000,length = 0x4000
        JTAGSIGNATURE           : origin = 0xFF80, length = 0x0004, fill = 0xFFFF
    BSLSIGNATURE            : origin = 0xFF84, length = 0x0004, fill = 0xFFFF
    IPESIGNATURE            : origin = 0xFF88, length = 0x0008, fill = 0xFFFF
    INT00                   : origin = 0xFF90, length = 0x0002
    INT01                   : origin = 0xFF92, length = 0x0002
    INT02                   : origin = 0xFF94, length = 0x0002
    INT03                   : origin = 0xFF96, length = 0x0002
    INT04                   : origin = 0xFF98, length = 0x0002
    INT05                   : origin = 0xFF9A, length = 0x0002
    INT06                   : origin = 0xFF9C, length = 0x0002
    INT07                   : origin = 0xFF9E, length = 0x0002
    INT08                   : origin = 0xFFA0, length = 0x0002
    INT09                   : origin = 0xFFA2, length = 0x0002
    INT10                   : origin = 0xFFA4, length = 0x0002
    INT11                   : origin = 0xFFA6, length = 0x0002
    INT12                   : origin = 0xFFA8, length = 0x0002
    INT13                   : origin = 0xFFAA, length = 0x0002
    INT14                   : origin = 0xFFAC, length = 0x0002
    INT15                   : origin = 0xFFAE, length = 0x0002
    INT16                   : origin = 0xFFB0, length = 0x0002
    INT17                   : origin = 0xFFB2, length = 0x0002
    INT18                   : origin = 0xFFB4, length = 0x0002
    INT19                   : origin = 0xFFB6, length = 0x0002
    INT20                   : origin = 0xFFB8, length = 0x0002
    INT21                   : origin = 0xFFBA, length = 0x0002
    INT22                   : origin = 0xFFBC, length = 0x0002
    INT23                   : origin = 0xFFBE, length = 0x0002
    INT24                   : origin = 0xFFC0, length = 0x0002
    INT25                   : origin = 0xFFC2, length = 0x0002
    INT26                   : origin = 0xFFC4, length = 0x0002
    INT27                   : origin = 0xFFC6, length = 0x0002
    INT28                   : origin = 0xFFC8, length = 0x0002
    INT29                   : origin = 0xFFCA, length = 0x0002
    INT30                   : origin = 0xFFCC, length = 0x0002
    INT31                   : origin = 0xFFCE, length = 0x0002
    INT32                   : origin = 0xFFD0, length = 0x0002
    INT33                   : origin = 0xFFD2, length = 0x0002
    INT34                   : origin = 0xFFD4, length = 0x0002
    INT35                   : origin = 0xFFD6, length = 0x0002
    INT36                   : origin = 0xFFD8, length = 0x0002
    INT37                   : origin = 0xFFDA, length = 0x0002
    INT38                   : origin = 0xFFDC, length = 0x0002
    INT39                   : origin = 0xFFDE, length = 0x0002
    INT40                   : origin = 0xFFE0, length = 0x0002
    INT41                   : origin = 0xFFE2, length = 0x0002
    INT42                   : origin = 0xFFE4, length = 0x0002
    INT43                   : origin = 0xFFE6, length = 0x0002
    INT44                   : origin = 0xFFE8, length = 0x0002
    INT45                   : origin = 0xFFEA, length = 0x0002  // TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
//    INT45                   : origin = 0xFF5A, length = 0x0002
    INT46                   : origin = 0xFFEC, length = 0x0002
    INT47                   : origin = 0xFFEE, length = 0x0002
    INT48                   : origin = 0xFFF0, length = 0x0002
    INT49                   : origin = 0xFFF2, length = 0x0002
    INT50                   : origin = 0xFFF4, length = 0x0002
    INT51                   : origin = 0xFFF6, length = 0x0002
    INT52                   : origin = 0xFFF8, length = 0x0002
    INT53                   : origin = 0xFFFA, length = 0x0002
    INT54                   : origin = 0xFFFC, length = 0x0002
    RESET                   : origin = 0xFFFE, length = 0x0002

}

/****************************************************************************/
/* Specify the sections allocation into memory                              */
/****************************************************************************/

SECTIONS
{
    GROUP(RW_IPE)
    {
        GROUP(READ_WRITE_MEMORY)
        {
           .TI.persistent : {}              /* For #pragma persistent            */
           .cio           : {}              /* C I/O Buffer                      */
           .sysmem        : {}              /* Dynamic memory allocation area    */
        } PALIGN(0x0400), RUN_START(fram_rw_start)

        GROUP(IPENCAPSULATED_MEMORY)
        {
           .ipestruct     : {}              /* IPE Data structure                */
           .ipe           : {}              /* IPE                               */
           .ipe_const     : {}              /* IPE Protected constants           */
           .ipe:_isr      : {}              /* IPE ISRs                          */
           .ipe_vars      : type = NOINIT{} /* IPE variables                     */
        } PALIGN(0x0400), RUN_START(fram_ipe_start) RUN_END(fram_ipe_end) RUN_END(fram_rx_start)
    } > 0x4400

    .cinit            : {}  > FRAM          /* Initialization tables             */
    .pinit            : {}  > FRAM          /* C++ Constructor tables            */
    .binit            : {}  > FRAM          /* Boot-time Initialization tables   */
    .init_array       : {}  > FRAM          /* C++ Constructor tables            */
    .mspabi.exidx     : {}  > FRAM          /* C++ Constructor tables            */
    .mspabi.extab     : {}  > FRAM          /* C++ Constructor tables            */
#ifndef __LARGE_DATA_MODEL__
    .const            : {} > FRAM           /* Constant data                     */
#else
    .const            : {} >> FRAM | FRAM2  /* Constant data                     */
#endif

    .text:_isr        : {}  > FRAM          /* Code ISRs                         */
#ifndef __LARGE_DATA_MODEL__
    .text             : {} > FRAM           /* Code                              */
#else
    .text             : {} >> FRAM2 | FRAM  /* Code                              */
#endif
#ifdef __TI_COMPILER_VERSION
  #if __TI_COMPILER_VERSION >= 15009000
    #ifndef __LARGE_DATA_MODEL__
    .TI.ramfunc : {} load=FRAM, run=RAM, table(BINIT)
    #else
    .TI.ramfunc : {} load=FRAM | FRAM2, run=RAM, table(BINIT)
    #endif
  #endif
#endif

    .jtagsignature : {} > JTAGSIGNATURE     /* JTAG Signature                    */
    .bslsignature  : {} > BSLSIGNATURE      /* BSL Signature                     */

    GROUP(SIGNATURE_SHAREDMEMORY)
    {
        .ipesignature  : {}                 /* IPE Signature                     */
        .jtagpassword  : {}                 /* JTAG Password                     */
    } > IPESIGNATURE

    .bss        : {} > RAM                  /* Global & static vars              */
    .data       : {} > RAM                  /* Global & static vars              */
    .TI.noinit  : {} > RAM                  /* For #pragma noinit                */
    .stack      : {} > RAM (HIGH)           /* Software system stack             */

    .infoA     : {} > INFOA              /* MSP430 INFO FRAM  Memory segments */
    .infoB     : {} > INFOB
    .infoC     : {} > INFOC
    .infoD     : {} > INFOD

    /* MSP430 Interrupt vectors          */
    .int00       : {}               > INT00
    .int01       : {}               > INT01
    .int02       : {}               > INT02
    .int03       : {}               > INT03
    .int04       : {}               > INT04
    .int05       : {}               > INT05
    .int06       : {}               > INT06
    .int07       : {}               > INT07
    .int08       : {}               > INT08
    .int09       : {}               > INT09
    .int10       : {}               > INT10
    .int11       : {}               > INT11
    .int12       : {}               > INT12
    .int13       : {}               > INT13
    .int14       : {}               > INT14
    .int15       : {}               > INT15
    .int16       : {}               > INT16
    .int17       : {}               > INT17
    .int18       : {}               > INT18
    .int19       : {}               > INT19
    .int20       : {}               > INT20
    .int21       : {}               > INT21
    .int22       : {}               > INT22
    .int23       : {}               > INT23
    .int24       : {}               > INT24
    .int25       : {}               > INT25
    .int26       : {}               > INT26
    .int27       : {}               > INT27
    .int28       : {}               > INT28
    .int29       : {}               > INT29
    AES256       : { * ( .int30 ) } > INT30 type = VECT_INIT
    RTC          : { * ( .int31 ) } > INT31 type = VECT_INIT
    PORT4        : { * ( .int32 ) } > INT32 type = VECT_INIT
    PORT3        : { * ( .int33 ) } > INT33 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER3_A1    : { * ( .int34 ) } > INT34 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER3_A0    : { * ( .int35 ) } > INT35 type = VECT_INIT
    PORT2        : { * ( .int36 ) } > INT36 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER2_A1    : { * ( .int37 ) } > INT37 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER2_A0    : { * ( .int38 ) } > INT38 type = VECT_INIT
    PORT1        : { * ( .int39 ) } > INT39 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER1_A1    : { * ( .int40 ) } > INT40 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER1_A0    : { * ( .int41 ) } > INT41 type = VECT_INIT
    DMA          : { * ( .int42 ) } > INT42 type = VECT_INIT
    USCI_A1      : { * ( .int43 ) } > INT43 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER0_A1    : { * ( .int44 ) } > INT44 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER0_A0    : { * ( .int45 ) } > INT45 type = VECT_INIT
    ADC12        : { * ( .int46 ) } > INT46 type = VECT_INIT
    USCI_B0      : { * ( .int47 ) } > INT47 type = VECT_INIT
    USCI_A0      : { * ( .int48 ) } > INT48 type = VECT_INIT
    WDT          : { * ( .int49 ) } > INT49 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER0_B1    : { * ( .int50 ) } > INT50 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMER0_B0    : { * ( .int51 ) } > INT51 type = VECT_INIT
    COMP_E       : { * ( .int52 ) } > INT52 type = VECT_INIT
    UNMI         : { * ( .int53 ) } > INT53 type = VECT_INIT
    SYSNMI       : { * ( .int54 ) } > INT54 type = VECT_INIT
    .reset       : {}               > RESET  /* MSP430 Reset vector         */
}

/****************************************************************************/
/* MPU/IPE Specific memory segment definitons                               */
/****************************************************************************/

#ifdef _IPE_ENABLE
   #define IPE_MPUIPLOCK 0x0080
   #define IPE_MPUIPENA 0x0040
   #define IPE_MPUIPPUC 0x0020

   // Evaluate settings for the control setting of IP Encapsulation
   #if defined(_IPE_ASSERTPUC1)
        #if defined(_IPE_LOCK ) && (_IPE_ASSERTPUC1 == 0x08))
         fram_ipe_enable_value = (IPE_MPUIPENA | IPE_MPUIPPUC |IPE_MPUIPLOCK);
        #elif defined(_IPE_LOCK )
         fram_ipe_enable_value = (IPE_MPUIPENA | IPE_MPUIPLOCK);
      #elif (_IPE_ASSERTPUC1 == 0x08)
         fram_ipe_enable_value = (IPE_MPUIPENA | IPE_MPUIPPUC);
      #else
         fram_ipe_enable_value = (IPE_MPUIPENA);
      #endif
   #else
      #if defined(_IPE_LOCK )
         fram_ipe_enable_value = (IPE_MPUIPENA | IPE_MPUIPLOCK);
      #else
         fram_ipe_enable_value = (IPE_MPUIPENA);
      #endif
   #endif

   // Segment definitions
   #ifdef _IPE_MANUAL                  // For custom sizes selected in the GUI
      fram_ipe_border1 = (_IPE_SEGB1>>4);
      fram_ipe_border2 = (_IPE_SEGB2>>4);
   #else                           // Automated sizes generated by the Linker
      fram_ipe_border2 = fram_ipe_end >> 4;
      fram_ipe_border1 = fram_ipe_start >> 4;
   #endif

   fram_ipe_settings_struct_address = Ipe_settingsStruct >> 4;
   fram_ipe_checksum = ~((fram_ipe_enable_value & fram_ipe_border2 & fram_ipe_border1) | (fram_ipe_enable_value & ~fram_ipe_border2 & ~fram_ipe_border1) | (~fram_ipe_enable_value & fram_ipe_border2 & ~fram_ipe_border1) | (~fram_ipe_enable_value & ~fram_ipe_border2 & fram_ipe_border1));
#endif

#ifdef _MPU_ENABLE
   #define MPUPW (0xA500)    /* MPU Access Password */
   #define MPUENA (0x0001)   /* MPU Enable */
   #define MPULOCK (0x0002)  /* MPU Lock */
   #define MPUSEGIE (0x0010) /* MPU Enable NMI on Segment violation */

   __mpu_enable = 1;
   // Segment definitions
   #ifdef _MPU_MANUAL // For custom sizes selected in the GUI
      mpu_segment_border1 = _MPU_SEGB1 >> 4;
      mpu_segment_border2 = _MPU_SEGB2 >> 4;
      mpu_sam_value = (_MPU_SAM0 << 12) | (_MPU_SAM3 << 8) | (_MPU_SAM2 << 4) | _MPU_SAM1;
   #else // Automated sizes generated by Linker
      #ifdef _IPE_ENABLE //if IPE is used in project too
         //seg1 = any read + write persistent variables
         //seg2 = ipe = read + write + execute access
         //seg3 = code, read + execute only
         mpu_segment_border1 = fram_ipe_start >> 4;
         mpu_segment_border2 = fram_rx_start >> 4;
         mpu_sam_value = 0x1573; // Info R, Seg3 RX, Seg2 RWX, Seg1 RW
      #else
         mpu_segment_border1 = fram_rx_start >> 4;
         mpu_segment_border2 = fram_rx_start >> 4;
         mpu_sam_value = 0x1513; // Info R, Seg3 RX, Seg2 R, Seg1 RW
      #endif
   #endif
   #ifdef _MPU_LOCK
      #ifdef _MPU_ENABLE_NMI
         mpu_ctl0_value = MPUPW | MPUENA | MPULOCK | MPUSEGIE;
      #else
         mpu_ctl0_value = MPUPW | MPUENA | MPULOCK;
      #endif
   #else
      #ifdef _MPU_ENABLE_NMI
         mpu_ctl0_value = MPUPW | MPUENA | MPUSEGIE;
      #else
         mpu_ctl0_value = MPUPW | MPUENA;
      #endif
   #endif
#endif

/****************************************************************************/
/* Include peripherals memory map                                           */
/****************************************************************************/

-l msp430fr5969.cmd
```

But how to do if i want to move all Interrputs vectors After the FRAM (0x4400 + 0xBB00= 0xFF00) (Move IV 0x80 before the standard address).

The aim is to fit this application with Custom Bootloader.

Thx,

Answer (score 1):

The interrupt vector table is located either at a fixed address in FRAM (0xFF80), or at a fixed address in SRAM (0x2380).
It is not possible to move it "after the FRAM".

To move the table to RAM,

1. adjust the linker script to move the stack out of the way;
2. copy your interrupt vectors to the end of the SRAM;
3. set the SYSRIVECT bit.

Comment: This is also true for MSP430FR5969 ? Have you a code sample for doing this reloc'?

Comment: There is no sample.

Comment: What do you mean by "move the stack out of the way;" & "copy your interrupt vectors to the end of the SRAM;"

Answer (score 1):

Even though, you can't freely move the vectors, you can "jump" from vector subroutines of your bootloader to the known addresses, which you can pick as you like. Knowing these addresses you can implement kind-of secondary interrupt vector table (let's say in separate code section, which you can manage from your linker script). This will provide you with the flexibility you are looking for your application to be started from your Custom Bootloader.